# ObservableCollection.Clear leaving phantom elements

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a set of converters that are used dynamically position squares on a canvas. The squares are stored in an observable collection. `CanvasPositionScaleConverter` converts a value within a range to a value between 0 and 1. If the value it is converting is outside the specified range, it will throw an Argument exception.

My issue is when I clear my squares collection, whilst the screen becomes empty, "phantom" elements seem to be left behind which the converters continue to act on. Therefore, when the canvas is resized, I still get exceptions being thrown, even if the squares collection has been cleared.

Why are the converters still running on these elements that have been deleted through `Squares.Clear()`?

---

*Note*

Using `Squares = new ObservableCollection<Square>()` instead of `Squares.Clear()` still causes this issue.

---

**Update**

This issue does not happen if the `Sqaures` collection is never added too and `Resize` is pressed. It only happens if elements have been deleted from the collection (and obviously if haven't been removed from the collection but are outside the valid range).

The exception details are

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in LateExceptionMcve.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in LateExceptionMcve.dll
Value cannot be greater than max
```

---

**MCVE**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="LateExceptionMcve.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LateExceptionMcve"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Stretch="Uniform">
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Black">
                <Border.Resources>
                    <local:CanvasScaleConverter x:Key="CanvasScaleConverter" />
                    <local:CanvasPositionScaleConverter x:Key="CanvasPositionScaleConverter" />
                </Border.Resources>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}"
                                  Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource CanvasScaleConverter}}"
                                  Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource CanvasScaleConverter}}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasPositionScaleConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="X" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Min" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Max" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Size"
                                                     Converter="{StaticResource CanvasScaleConverter}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasPositionScaleConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Y" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Min" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Max" />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" 
                                                     Path="DataContext.Size"
                                                     Converter="{StaticResource CanvasScaleConverter}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="Red" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </Viewbox>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Clear"
                Click="Clear" />

        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Resize"
                Click="Resize" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace LateExceptionMcve
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Min = 0;
            Max = 10;
            Size = Max - Min;
            Squares = new ObservableCollection<Square>
            {
                new Square
                {
                    X = 8,
                    Y = 7,
                },
            };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Resize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Min = 0;
            Max = 5;
            Size = Max - Min;
        }

        private void Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Squares.Clear();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Square> _squares;

        public ObservableCollection<Square> Squares
        {
            get => _squares;
            set
            {
                _squares = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double _size;

        public double Size
        {
            get => _size;
            set
            {
                _size = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double _min;

        public double Min
        {
            get => _min;
            set
            {
                _min = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double _max;

        public double Max
        {
            get => _max;
            set
            {
                _max = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Square : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private double _x;

        public double X
        {
            get => _x;
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double _y;

        public double Y
        {
            get => _y;
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class CanvasScaleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private const double Scale = 100;

        public object Convert(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double valueToScale)
            {
                return valueToScale * Scale;
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public sealed class CanvasPositionScaleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(
            object[] values,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length == 4 &&
                values[0] is double value &&
                values[1] is double min &&
                values[2] is double max &&
                values[3] is double canvasWidthHeight)
            {
                return canvasWidthHeight * RangeToNormalizedValue(min, max, value);
            }

            return values;
        }

        private static double RangeToNormalizedValue(
            double min,
            double max,
            double value)
        {
            if (min > max)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Min cannot be less than max");
            }

            if (value < min)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be less than min");
            }

            if (value > max)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be greater than max");
            }

            return (value - min) / (max - min);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(
            object value,
            Type[] targetTypes,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I have filled a [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3210) on the WPF GitHub repo, so hopefully that may help find what is going on here.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try assign to null first.

Comment: @SilnyToJa This stops the exception specified in the question being thrown but causes `System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. Object[]:'System.Object[]' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Left' (type 'Double')`. I have a feeling that is because a `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is being passed into the converter after setting it to null. This is not ideal and still happens after the resize is called so doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @XAMlMAX That's plain nonsense. Calling `Clear()` on an ObservableCollection does *of course* fire an appropriate CollectionChanged event.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thanks for the comment. Whilst I agree with @Clemens about the `Clear()`, I tried the `BindingList` and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Clemens Is there any chance you might know what is happening here?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Also, in regards to assigning a new instance, I mentioned in the question that this produces the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information from [miloush](https://github.com/miloush) on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3210#issuecomment-653686738).

The cause of this issue is that even though the `Squares` collection has been cleared and the objects are no longer visible on the screen, the objects have not been garbage collected.

It is possible to force the garbage collection to happen by modifying the `Clear` method to something like

```
private void Clear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Squares.Clear();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(GC.Collect), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

And this will (eventually) clear the objects away. However, it is not immediate. Even if just `GC.Collect()` after `Squares.Clear` had been called it is not immediate.

This  issue could occur at many times in WPF, including in common actions such as virtualisation. Therefore it would be better to update the converter so it can handle invalid inputs gracefully.

```
public sealed class CanvasPositionScaleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 4 ||
            !(values[0] is double value) ||
            !(values[1] is double min) ||
            !(values[2] is double max) ||
            !(values[3] is double canvasWidthHeight))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            return canvasWidthHeight * RangeToNormalizedValue(min, max, value);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e) when (e.Message == ValueLessThanMin)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e) when (e.Message == ValueGreaterThanMax)
        {
            return canvasWidthHeight;
        }
    }

    // This is in a utility class normally
    private const string ValueLessThanMin = "Value cannot be less than min";
    private const string ValueGreaterThanMax = "Value cannot be greater than max";

    private static double RangeToNormalizedValue(
        double min,
        double max,
        double value)
    {
        if (min > max)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Min cannot be less than max");
        }

        if (value < min)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ValueLessThanMin);
        }

        if (value > max)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ValueGreaterThanMax);
        }

        return (value - min) / (max - min);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the error cannot be caused by the garbage collector.
XAML uses Binding - it uses weak references.
Сonverter-CanvasPositionScaleConverter can only be called by an object from the Squares collection.
Objects removed from this collection cannot in any way call the CanvasPositionScaleConverter.

Comment: I completely copied your code, but could not reproduce your problem.
Try to create a separate project with this code only and run it.
Will the same error or not?
Perhaps this error does appear not due to this code.

Comment: @EldHasp It's odd that it is not reproduced on your machine. I have a repo with a .NET Framework and a .NET Core reproduction of this issue (using the code from the question), [https://github.com/DanJBower/ConverterBug](https://github.com/DanJBower/ConverterBug). I have deleted the projects and cloned this on both my desktop PC and my laptop and the issue happens in both .NET Framework and .NET Core on both machines. Could you try cloning this repo to see if it happens in either framework?

Comment: maybe I'm checking your code incorrectly?
I have no exceptions.
I will describe what I am doing:
1) Copy the Repository;
2) Launched a project;
3) A window with one small square appeared;
4) Pressed the "Clear" button - the square disappeared;
5) I resize the window while holding the window border with the mouse;
6) I click the "Resize" button.

Not a single exception occurred at any step.

Comment: @EldHasp If you do all that without step 5 (actually resizing the window), I think you will get the exception. I did what you did, and I don't get the exception either, but if you just press clear then click resize, I get the exception